# How to define default action parameters in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am following Pluralsight videos to learn MVC4.

While learning about default values for action parameters I have defined the following setting inside RouteConfig.cs

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "cuisine",
            url: "cuisine/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller="cuisine", action="search", name=""});
```

I have created CuisineController with Search() as the action method like below:

```
    public ActionResult Search(string name="India")
    {
        var message = Server.HtmlEncode(name);
        return Content(message);
    }
```

As per the video I have seen, if nothing is passed in the URL then India should come as output.
But, I am getting empty string.
Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: what if you remove name="" from route defaults?

Comment: "name" is required as it is the part of "url" parameter - {name}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use UrlParameter.Optional

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{name}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

public ActionResult Search(string name = "India")
        {
            var message = Server.HtmlEncode(name);
            return Content(message);
        }
```

This displayed "India" perfectly in page.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reqply.
I have used the following URL to call Search Action method in my CuisineController.
http://localhost:51468/cuisine/
This means that I have not passed any parameter, right? Even then I am NOT getting India as output.

Comment: You have to use UrlParameter.Optional. I have edited my answer, check it out. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot SMS. You are right. I have marked your answer. With my action, your two down votes are gone. Thanks once again.